# SwiftUI: `Toggle`s within dynamic `List` breaking their layout upon reuse?

Tags: ios, toggle, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to show a dynamic `List` with rows containing `Toggle` elements. The `Toggle`s are laid out correctly initially, but their layout breaks when scrolling them in and out of view (i. e. upon cell reuse).

Minimal example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwitchList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<20) { _ in
            SwitchRow(value: Bool.random())
        }
    }
}

struct SwitchRow: View {
    @State var value: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $value) {
            Text("A switch row")
        }
    }
}
```

Screen recording demonstrating the issue:
[image: Toggles in a list have the correct layout initially, but break their layout upon scrolling]

(This is using iOS 13.2.2 (17B102) on the Simulator.)

**Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? How do I get the `Toggle`s to show correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a bug/regression in iOS 13.2+**

Working - iOS 13.1 (17A844) / Xcode 11.1 (11A1027)
Broken - iOS 13.2.2 (17B102) / Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500)
Broken - iOS 13.3 beta (17C5032d) / Xcode 11.3 beta (11C24b)

[Submit feedback to Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com)

**Workaround**

This bug only appears to affect the `List` initializers which take a `data` parameter. This code is functionally equivalent, but is not affected by the bug.

```
struct SwitchList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                SwitchRow(value: Bool.random())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem, but could not find out why this happens. When I use a `ScrollView()` with a `Divider()` I don't have the Problem anymore. Here is the code:

```
struct SwitchList: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack {
                    SwitchRow(value: Bool.random())
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwitchRow: View {
    @State var value: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $value) {
            Text("A switch row")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!