# Long List with Textfields in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I try to do a List with SwiftUI where you can insert two Strings in Textfields and one Boolean Button in each Row. However when the list exceeds the screen and you scroll to the last rows they sometimes erase the content. 
I created a minimal example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bindOne = "one"
    @State var bindTwo = "two"
    @State var bindThree = "three"
    @State var bindFour = "four"
    @State var bindFive = "five"
    @State var bindSix = "six"
    @State var buttonValue = false


    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("test")
                .font(.largeTitle)

        List{
            Row(someBind: bindOne, buttonValue: false)
            Row(someBind: bindTwo, buttonValue: false)
            Row(someBind: bindThree, buttonValue: false)
            Row(someBind: bindFour, buttonValue: false)
            Row(someBind: bindFive, buttonValue: false)
            Row(someBind: bindSix, buttonValue: false)

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

with the supporting View:

```swift
struct Row: View {
    @State var someBind: String
    @State var buttonValue: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            TextField(someBind, text: $someBind)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            TextField(someBind, text: $someBind)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Button(action: {self.buttonValue.toggle()}){
                if buttonValue{
                    Text("Yes")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }else{
                    Text("No")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 70)

    }
}
```

The result is

[image: screenshot]

When the lines fit on the screen there is no problem, but sometimes you just have a long list.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use? You might face the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930429/swiftui-list-uiviewrepresantable-wont-be-updated)

Comment: I am using 11.2.1 (11B500). Yeah could be connected.

Comment: Its working finde for me on 11.1

Comment: confirm issue on 13.2, works on 13.0

Comment: There seems to be a lot of problems in 11.2+ with `List` row layouts after scrolling. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920581/3088606) as well, and [file feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com)

Comment: Ok I will send feedback. The workaround in the answer you stated didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not present anymore. Checked with Xcode *Version 11.4.1 (11E503a)*.